# Версия php

Tags: ubuntu

Добрый день. Подскажите как можно узнать в каком дистрибутиве была версия php 5.2.* ? Порылся [тут](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), номеров версий не обнаружил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5.2 нет в поддерживаемых

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php5&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

см сюда:

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/

Comment: спасибо, я искал по слову php, надо было по php5.

Answer (score 0):

> Начиная с Ubuntu 10.04 и выше по умолчанию устанавливается PHP версии 5.3

Comment: а как об этом можно узнать кроме как установить и проверить? Если конечно это вообще возможно.

Comment: Не понимаю чего вы хотите? Можно и не устанавливать, скачайте образ, сделайте mount, посмотрите версию пакета в образе ?!